# Python change log level in config file without restarting program

Tags: python, logging, configuration

I would like to set up my logger in Python such that every time there is a log event, the logger checks a config file for the log level so that the log level can be changed while the program is running.  Could anyone recommend a way of doing this?

I tried setting the log level to a function that would read the log level from a config, something like: my_logger.setLevel(read_log_level_from_config()) but this still only sets the log level/reads from the config on the first time.

Comment: You'd had to create a custom FileHandler and define `emit` method to it. See [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html)s. `emit` triggered whenever there's a log that needs to be written to a file. So you would have to check the log level, set it, and then set it to `DEBUG` or `emit` won't trigger on the next log.